# iPhone statistics access to client

Tags: iphone

I have created a iPhone application and got successfully approved by apple. The  application has been uploaded in my company's developer account.

Now my client wants access to see the sales report. I cannot give him my company's developer account log in details because the account has many applications other than my client's.

Is there a way to allow access to my client to see the financial reports for his applications alone.

What are the alternatives available.

#### Update:

My client is particular that he wants to log in and see.

As per my knowledge, the only way he can see the report details is if I had uploaded the application  using his own developer account.

One of the developer says,

"We will submit the iPhone application to app store from your iTunes appStore account. SO you will naturally have the access to all the available data. Please note that you need to buy a paid account for submitting the application to app store"

Does the iTunes appStore account mentioned above refers to developer account or is it different

Answer (score 4):

If your client does not already have a developer account, he needs to enroll into the Developer Program and resubmit the App through his Developer ID. This will require an annual $99 fee to maintain access to iTunes Connect.

There is no "Sales Report Viewing" account...  Apple will pay HIM for the sales of the App, not you. It sounds like you are paying **Him** now for his App sales from iTunes Connect.

If it's his App and you simply did the programming work, then you should have submitted it through his Developer Program plan in the first place - not yours.  He should have given YOU access to iTunes Connect through his plan to submit the App, or have done that work himself.

Next time, you'll need to build this level of detail into the contract - specifically whether you will be paying him a monthly commission on sales, or he paid you for your time and the App is now his to manage with Apple.

-t

Answer (score 0):

One idea: you could make a modified version of AppSalesMobile that has your iTunesConnect username, password, and the apple ID of his particular app built in, but didn't display information about any other apps, and build him a copy for his phone.

http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

Might be easier to just send him the sales in an email every day, though.